# Sorting on a enterprise keyword column

Tags: 2013, enterprise-keywords

Ive been asked a question about sorting on an enterprise keyword column and it doesnt seem this is possible.  Ive also looked to create a view and as expected its not available in the sorting dropdown. Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Create a Managed Metadata column](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/sharepoint-server-help/create-a-managed-metadata-column-HA101631602.aspx)

> In the Multiple Value field section, specify whether you want to allow
>   multiple values in the column. If you allow multiple values, users
>   will not be able to sort on this column in list views
>   [image]

Since built-in `Enterprise Keywords` column (`TaxKeyword`) is Multiple Value field it could not be specified in List View sorting.